# Plotting curves with different point styles in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using Gnuplot to draw a graph. In the graph I drew three smooth curve belonging to three data sets.

Presently I'm using the following Gnuplot script.

```
reset
set terminal png
set xlabel "Square matrix size"

set ylabel "Time (in milliseconds)"
set yrange [0:750]

set title "Lower Triangular Matrix"
set key reverse Left outside
set grid
set output 'matrixlt.png'
set style data linespoints
plot "matrixlowertriangle.dat" using 1:2 lt 1 lw 2 smooth bezier title 'MatPro', \
     "matrixlowertriangle.dat" using 1:3 lt 2 lw 2 smooth bezier title 'C#' , \
     "matrixlowertriangle.dat" using 1:4 lt 3 lw 2 smooth bezier title 'C++'
```

With the above script I'm getting following graph.
[image]

Now I want to draw each point belonging to the same curve using a unique point style. ( For example each point belonging to C# using one point type and C++ data points in a different style.)

I tried some tutorials, but still no luck. Can somebody help me to achieve this task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have your data so I made some up (it always helps to be helpful if some useful mock dataset is given...):

```
0   0   0   0
200 1000    1200    1500
400 4000    7000    9000
600 7000    15000   18000
800 12000   23000   25000
1000    18000   33000   40000
```

Based upon your code, I tried

```
reset
set terminal png
set xlabel "Square matrix size"

set ylabel "Time (in milliseconds)"
set xrange [0:1200]
set yrange [0:50000]


set title "Lower Triangular Matrix"
set key reverse Left outside
set grid
set output 'matrixlt.png'
set style data linespoints
plot "matrixlowertriangle.dat" using 1:2 lt 1 lw 2 smooth bezier title 'MatPro', \
     "matrixlowertriangle.dat" using 1:3 lt 2 lw 2 smooth bezier title 'C#' , \
     "matrixlowertriangle.dat" using 1:4 lt 3 lw 2 smooth bezier title 'C++' , \
     "matrixlowertriangle.dat" using 1:2 with points title "", \
     "matrixlowertriangle.dat" using 1:3 with points title "", \
     "matrixlowertriangle.dat" using 1:4 with points title ""
```

and got

[image: this graph here]

Is that closer to what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to supply `pointtype X` (where X is a number) to the plot arguments ?

Comment: I think it is better if you edit your question and add some info about your gnuplot build

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is associated with using the PNG terminal. Do you have to use PNG format? If you try `set terminal postscript enhanced eps color`, the script produces figures with clearly distinguishable line types.

For example, running the following simple script:

```
set terminal postscript enhanced eps color
set yrange [0:10]
set grid
set output 'test.eps'
set title 'EPS demonstration'
set style data linespoints

plot x*2 lt 1 lw 2 title 'A', \
     x**2 lt 2 lw 2 title 'B'
```

gives two lines with different linetypes.